# SnakeYaml Error Exception in parsing org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Unable to find property 'First' on class: JavaBeanObject

Tags: java, parsing, java-8, yaml, snakeyaml

can someone tell me the error in my SnakeYaml usage v1.19. Somehow it cannot serialize the object and I do not know why.

my JavaBeanObject.java

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
 
public class ConfigRunner {
    
    private static File myfile = new File(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"),"config", "trial.yml").toString());
    private static String mypath =myfile.getPath();
    private JavaBeanObject myparam;

    public static JavaBeanObject getConfiguration(String filePath) throws IOException{
        Constructor constructor = new Constructor(JavaBeanObject.class);
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);

        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(filePath))) {
            JavaBeanObject config = yaml.loadAs(in, JavaBeanObject.class);
            System.out.println(config.toString());
            return config;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(mypath);
            getConfiguration(mypath);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

My ConfigRunner:

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
 
public class ConfigRunner {

    private static File myfile = new File(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"),"config", "trial.yml").toString());
    private static String mypath =myfile.getPath();
    private JavaBeanObject myparam;

    public static JavaBeanObject getConfiguration(String filePath) throws IOException{
        Constructor constructor = new Constructor(JavaBeanObject.class);
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);

        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(filePath))) {
            JavaBeanObject config = yaml.loadAs(in, JavaBeanObject.class);
            System.out.println(config.toString());
            return config;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(mypath);
            getConfiguration(mypath);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

### My trial.yml

```
First: anton
Second: berta
Third: caesar
Fourth: Dora
```

---

Ok, the Problem I am facing here is with the Stringbuilder and it cannot serialize the object. The error that I get is:

```
C:\Users\domino\config\trial.yml

    Exception in thread "main" Cannot create property=First for JavaBean=First: null
    First: null
    Second: null
    Third: null
    Fourth: null
    
     in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
        First: 'anton ... 
                ^
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:313)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:190)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:346)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:141)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:127)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:450)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadAs(Yaml.java:444)
        at ConfigRunner.getConfiguration(ConfigRunner.java:26)
    
    Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Unable to find property 'First' on class: JavaBeanObject
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:132)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:121)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.getProperty(Constructor.java:323)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:241)
        at ConfigRunner.main(ConfigRunner.java:36)
```

Can someone help explain the error?

Comment: It seems that you pasted the wrong code for JavaBeanObject. Can you paste it (if not too late) ?